# SQL: How to concatenate two cells from one column of multiple rows if all of the other row's cells are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for `DepartmentName1 + ', ' + DepartmentName2`

I'm trying to merge two rows into one row when only one column has different values. Specifically I'm trying to list the name, job title, gender, pay rate, hire date and department name of the top 100 highest paid employees of the AdventureWorks2017 database. Here is the code I have so far:

```sql
        SELECT TOP 100 (P.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName) AS Name, HRE.JobTitle, HRE.Gender,  
    CAST(HRPH.Rate AS Decimal(10,2)) AS PayRate, HRE.HireDate, HRD.Name AS Department  
    FROM ((((Person.Person AS P  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS HRE  
        ON P.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN  
        (SELECT BusinessEntityID, MAX(RateChangeDate) AS RCD, MAX(Rate) AS Rate  
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory  
        GROUP BY BusinessEntityID) AS HRPH  
        ON HRE.BusinessEntityID = HRPH.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS HRDH  
        ON HRE.BusinessEntityID = HRDH.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS HRD  
        ON HRDH.DepartmentID = HRD.DepartmentID)  
    ORDER BY HRPH.Rate DESC;
```

This gives me the following result:

[image: Screenshot of database result]

Two questions:

1. How can I get every 'Name' to be listed only once, regardless of DepartmentName? For example: Rows 5 & 6 to be only Row 5: Laura Norman | Chief Financial Officer | F | 60.10 | 2009-01-31 | Executive, Finance.


   OR, David Bradley...|...Marketing, Purchasing
2. Does my code include an employee that may have gotten a pay cut? Meaning, the RateChangeDate (RCD) is MAX but the Rate is not?

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Which DBMS and version number are you using?

Comment: Using MS SQL Server Management  Studio 18

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Comment: Surely you can test question 2 yourself with some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you can make use of the string_agg() to aggregate the values with a delimiter in a query field.

```
   SELECT TOP 100 (P.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName) AS Name, HRE.JobTitle, HRE.Gender,  
    CAST(HRPH.Rate AS Decimal(10,2)) AS PayRate, HRE.HireDate, STRING_AGG(HRD.Name,',') AS Department  
    FROM ((((Person.Person AS P  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS HRE  
        ON P.BusinessEntityID = HRE.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN  
        (SELECT BusinessEntityID, MAX(RateChangeDate) AS RCD, MAX(Rate) AS Rate  
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory  
        GROUP BY BusinessEntityID) AS HRPH  
        ON HRE.BusinessEntityID = HRPH.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS HRDH  
        ON HRE.BusinessEntityID = HRDH.BusinessEntityID)  
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS HRD  
        ON HRDH.DepartmentID = HRD.DepartmentID)  
    GROUP BY P.FirstName,P.LastName,HRE.JobTitle, HRE.Gender, HRPH.Rate, HRE.HireDate
    ORDER BY HRPH.Rate DESC;
```

To answer the second part, I took the liberty of creating an example and you may be able to work into your solution. The data you are working with lacks a unique key and using FirstName, LastName, and Gender is an obviously bad candidate for a unique key. You also mention RateChangeDate but do not mention how to handle that value when the data aggregates. The query below basically ignores RateChangeDate on the output and marks the records that have a decrease in pay. Another query into the data is needed to remove those records, below I did it using a HAVING clause.

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (ID INT, Rate MONEY, RateChangeDate DATETIME, Department NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT @X VALUES
(1,25.00,'01/01/2021','A'),
(1,23.00,'05/01/2021','A'),
(2,25.00,'01/01/2021','A'),
(3,25.00,'01/01/2021','A'),
(3,26.00,'02/01/2021','A'),
(4,25.00,'01/01/2021','A'),
(4,25.00,'01/01/2021','B')
SELECT
    ID,
    SUM(LatestRate) AS LatestRate,
    MAX(MaxRateChange) AS RateChanges,
    Departments
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        STRING_AGG(Department,',') AS Departments,
        Rate,
        MAX(RateChangeDate) AS MaxRateChange,
        CASE WHEN LAG(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RateChangeDate) > Rate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DecreaseInPay,
        CASE WHEN MAX(RateChangeDate)OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = RateChangeDate THEN Rate ELSE NULL END LatestRate
    FROM 
        @X
    GROUP BY
        ID,Rate,RateChangeDate
)AS X
GROUP BY
    ID,Departments
HAVING
    MAX(DecreaseInPay) = 0
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Any ideas about the second part of the question regarding the RateChangeDate and PayRate? I'm thinking that my current code won't include any employee who's RateChangeDate is more recent but perhaps includes a pay cut.

Comment: I added an example of one way to approach your second part.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you so much for taking the time to help. I'm learning SQL and you have helped me have a better grasp on the material.